# How to use variable defined in for-loop outside of it?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

How can I use this  `u_name` and `u_pass` outside this `for` loop?

```
cursr.execute("SELECT rowid ,* FROM usernameandpassword")
user_and_pass = (cursr.fetchall())

for users in user_and_pass:
    global u_name
    global u_pass
    u_name = (users[1])
    u_pass = (users[2])

    if uni_username.get() == u_name and uni_pass.get() == u_pass:
        show_new_user_window()
```

Comment: u_name and u_pass are still in the namespace when the for loop exits, but they'll be the last entries in the ```user_and_pass``` list.  are you trying to keep a list of usernames and passwords?

Comment: yes  , because if i use u_name and u_pass outside for loop , I can get only last entry

Comment: [Global variables are _evil_!](//stackoverflow.com/q/19158339/843953) You can almost always replace global variables with something else to get the same behavior without all the pain that global variables bring.

Comment: Those variables are available outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

you could create another two lists like `name_list` and `pass_list`, and initialize them before for-loop and inside for loop use `name_list.append(user[1])`, `pass_list.append(user[2])`, after for-loop use index to get each name and pass

```
# intialize name_list and pass_list lists
name_list = []
pass_list = []
for users in user_and_pass:
    # save them into our lists
    name_list.append(users[1])
    pass_list.append(users[2])
```

outside this for loop, `name_list[0]` will refer to the first value, `name_list[1]` will refer to second value and so on.

Comment: what do you mean by that 'after for-loop use index to get each name and pass' can you explain , because  I am beginner I don't know too much